# Parse XML in Java with data next to attribute

Tags: java, xml, parsing, openstreetmap

I need to get the value of certain XML objects in Java, but they are in the attribute tag. I'm not sure how to go about this.

XML Example:

```
<node id="359832" version="5" timestamp="2008-05-20T15:20:46Z" uid="4499" changeset="486842" lat="50.9051565" lon="6.963755">
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Campus"/>
  </node>
  <node id="451153" version="4" timestamp="2009-09-17T18:09:14Z" uid="508" changeset="2514480" lat="51.6020306" lon="-0.1935029">
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="created_by" v="JOSM"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Sun and Sea"/>
  </node>
```

I need to get the value of `lat` and `lon`, which are inside of the `<node>` in addition to the value of `<tag k="name" v="Sun and Sea"/>`, and with each set of this, do something with it.

Pseudocode:

```
foreach(node in xmlFile)
{
String name = this.name;
double lat = this.lat;
double lon = this.lon;
//my own thing here
}
```

I have looked, but am unable to find anything on how to get the values for `lat` and `lon`, since they are next to the attribute instead of nested. I don't need to use an input-stream, the xml file is small enough that I cant store it in memory.

Comment: what parsing library are you using?

Comment: I am trying to do it with DOM, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(Sandbox.class.getResourceAsStream("/foo.xml"));

        NodeList nodeNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("node");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeNodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node nNode = nodeNodeList.item(i);

            System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lat").getNodeValue());
            System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lon").getNodeValue());

        }

    }


}
```

This printed out:

```
50.9051565
6.963755
51.6020306
-0.1935029
```